# How do I fix USER FATAL MESSAGE 740?

Tags: nastran

How do I fix USER FATAL MESSAGE 740? This error is generated by Nastran when I try to run a BDF/DAT file of mine.

```
*** USER FATAL MESSAGE 740 (RDASGN)
     UNIT NUMBER     5 HAS ALREADY BEEN ASSIGNED TO THE LOGICAL NAME INPUT
     USER ACTION: CHANGE THE UNIT NUMBER ON THE ASSIGN STATEMENT AND IF THE UNIT IS USED FOR
                  PARAM,POST,<0 THEN SPECIFY PARAM,OUNIT2 WITH THE NEW UNIT NUMBER.
                  AVOID USING THE FOLLOWING UNIT NUMBERS THAT ARE ASSIGNED TO SPECIAL FILES IN MSC.NASTRAN:
                  1 THRU 12, 14 THRU 22, 40, 50, 51, 91, 92. SEE THE MSC.NASTRAN INSTALLATIONS/OPERATIONS
                  GUIDE SECTION ON MAKING FILE ASSIGNMENTS OR MSC.NASTRAN QUICK REFERENCE GUIDE ON
                  ASSIGN PHYSICAL FILE FOR REFERENCE.
```

Below is the head of my BDF file.

```
assign userfile='SUB1_PLATE.csv', status=UNKNOWN, form=formatted, unit=52
SOL 200
CEND
ECHO = NONE
DESOBJ(MIN) = 35
set 30=1008,1007,1015,1016
DESMOD=SUB1_PLATE
SUBCASE 1
$! Subcase name : DefaultLoadCase
$LBCSET  SUBCASE1       DefaultLbcSet
   ANALYSIS = STATICS
   SPC = 1
   LOAD = 6
   DESSUB = 99
   DISPLACEMENT(SORT1,PLOT,REAL)=ALL
   STRESS(SORT1,PLOT,VONMISES,CORNER)=ALL
BEGIN BULK
param,xyunit,52
[...]
ENDDATA
```

Comment: If the provided answer helped you, accept and upvote it to support the volunteers that help you here. If not, leave some feedback and better clarify your problem

Answer (score 2):

Below is the solution

Correct

```
assign userfile='SUB1_PLAT.csv', status=UNKNOWN, form=formatted, unit=52
```

I shortened the name of CSV file to SUB1_PLAT.csv. This reduced the length of the line to 72 characters.

Incorrect

```
assign userfile='SUB1_PLATE.csv', status=UNKNOWN, form=formatted, unit=52
```

The file management section is limited to 72 characters, spaces included. The incorrect line stretches 73 characters. The nastran reader ignores the 73rd character and on. Instead of reading "unit=52" the reader reads "unit=5" which triggers the error.

```
|<--------------------- 72 Characters -------------------------------->||<- Characters are ignored truncated ->
assign userfile='SUB1_PLATE.csv', status=UNKNOWN, form=formatted, unit=52
```

References

1. MSC Nastran Reference Guide

> The records of the first four sections are input in free-field format
> and only columns 1 through 72 are used for data. Any information in
> columns 73 through 80 may appear in the printed echo, but will not be
> used by the program. If the last character in a record is a comma,
> then the record is continued to the next record.